# RXJS buffer with time, count and tokenState

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm working on a http buffer that buffers the HTTP requests and send them after waiting an amount of time since the first request or when the buffer limit is reached. So it has to continue when:

- When the amount of calls is > 25
- After x ms after the first buffer call, but wait until the token observer === 'valid'.

After some trial and error I have developed this:

```
this.batcherObservable = new Subject<BatchItem>();
this.batcherObservable.pipe(
  tap(req => console.log(req.request.url)),
  bufferWhen(() => {
    // Buffer has opened
    const bufferStopt = new Subject()
    const limiter = this.batcherObservable.pipe(takeUntil(bufferStopt), bufferCount(26), take(1))
    const timer = this.batcherObservable.pipe(takeUntil(bufferStopt), take(1), delay(this.options.batchDelay))
    const tokensValid = this.batcherObservable.pipe(takeUntil(bufferStopt), take(1), delayWhen(() => this.tokenStatus.pipe(filter(state => state === 'valid'), take(1))))
    return race(limiter, forkJoin([timer, tokensValid])).pipe(tap( () => {
      bufferStopt.complete()
    }))
  }),
  filter(requests => requests.length > 0),
  tap(req => console.log(req.length)),
  delayWhen(() => this.tokenStatus.pipe(filter(state => state === 'valid'), take(1))),
).subscribe(async requests  => {
  const useBatch = requests.length > 1

  let request: Request = !useBatch ? requests[0].request : await this.#renderCallsToBatchCall(<[BatchItem, ...BatchItem[]]>requests)
  let response: globalThis.Response
  try {
    response = await firstValueFrom(this.#sendRequest(request))
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error in batch', error)
    if (error instanceof globalThis.Response) {
      response = await error.json()
    } else {
      console.error(error)
      return new Error('Error when requesting')
    }
  }

  if (!useBatch) {
    if(response.ok && (response.status >= 200 && response.status <= 299)) return requests[0].responseObserver.next(response)
    else return requests[0].responseObserver.error(response)
  }
  const batchBody: FlatResponse[]|CWHttpError = await response.json()
  
  // We have to flat out the batchcall and make our own responses
  requests.forEach((batchItem, index) => {
    if (Array.isArray(batchBody)) {
      const {body, headers, status, message} = batchBody[index]
      const url = requests[index].request.url
      response = new Response(JSON.stringify(body || {}), {headers, statusText: message, status: parseInt(status)})
      // URL is private of Response. This is the only way I can set the url
      Object.defineProperty(response, 'url', { value: url});
      if (response.ok) {
        batchItem.responseObserver.next(response)
      } else {
        batchItem.responseObserver.error(body)
      }
      batchItem.responseObserver.complete()
    } else {
      batchItem.responseObserver.error(response)
    }
  })
});
```

**Problem**
I can see that it triggers the request with 25 calls, but when I do 26 calls it does not trigger the buffer by the 26th call. It keeps getting stuck in the buffer. -25 and 27+ works perfectly. Can someone see the problem with my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This will fail to emit the last emission after 26 emissions of *batcherObservable*, either after its initialization or after any emissions from the **bufferWhen**.  So, for example, you can emit 45 requests, wait a bit and then try 26 is rapid succession, and that last request will never be returned.

What's happening happening is that when you first setup the stream, the logic inside **bufferWhen** is executed immediately, BUT the logic inside **bufferWhen** won't be executed again until after the first emission from *batcherObservable* after the last **bufferWhen**.  So the *limiter*, *timer*, and *tokensValid* observables won't start until the **NEXT** emission from *batcherObservable*.  This is why the 27th emission appears to work.

The easiest thing is to have those observables subscribe to a version of the batcher that uses **shareReplay**.  However this would have the adverse effect of constantly restarting the timer.  So if you haven't had a request for a while, and then just had one, it would be returned before the desired interval (though the elapsed interval between emissions would still be greater).

```
this.batcherObservable = new Subject<BatchItem>();
this.batcherObservableShared = batcherObservable.pipe(shareReplay(1));
batcherObservable
  .pipe(
    tap((x) => console.log(`buffering ${x}`)),
    bufferWhen(() => {
      // Buffer has opened
      const bufferStopt = new Subject();
      const limiter = batcherObservableShared.pipe(/*... */);
      const timer = batcherObservableShared.pipe(/*... */);
      const tokensValid = batcherObservableShared.pipe(/* .. */);
      return race(limiter, forkJoin([timer, tokensValid])).pipe(
        tap(() => bufferStopt.next())
      );
    }),
    /* ... */
```

I don't love this solution.  I've never used **bufferWhen** so maybe my observations can help somebody else find a better solution.